# Why is Casperjs fails to submit this form from time to time?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

This code opens Google, searches for `casperjs` and outputs the title of the page:

```
var results = []
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'debug',
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false, // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
    loadPlugins: false, // use these settings
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'
  }
})

casper.on("page.error", function(err, trace) {
  this.die("Page Error: " + err, "ERROR")
})

casper.on('complete.error', function(err) {
  this.die("Complete Error: " + err)
})

casper.start('http://google.co.uk/', function() {
  this.evaluate(function() {
        document.querySelector('input[name="q"]').value = "casperjs"
        document.querySelector('input[name="btnK"]').click()
  })
})

casper.then(function() {
  //this.echo(this.getHTML('form[action="/search"]'))
  results = this.evaluate(function() {
    return document.title
  })
})

casper.run(function() {
  this.echo(results).exit()
})
```

It submits the form most of the time:

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 3 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://google.co.uk/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://google.co.uk/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://www.google.co.uk/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/3 https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/3: done in 1139ms.
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&q=casperjs&btnK=Google+Search, type=FormSubmitted, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&q=casperjs&btnK=Google+Search"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3 https://www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&q=casperjs&btnK=Google+Search (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3: done in 3605ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 3 steps in 3641ms
casperjs - Google Search
```

But it fails at time:

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 3 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://google.co.uk/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://google.co.uk/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://www.google.co.uk/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/3 https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/3: done in 2003ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3 https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3: done in 2014ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 3 steps in 2033ms
Google
```

Why does this happen? Is it normal?

**EDIT:**

This is what `this.echo(this.getHTML('#gs_lc0'))` returns:

[image]

No idea why `value` isn't being set at times.

**EDIT 2:**

The problem disappears if I only write: `userAgent: 'Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'`

Maybe the Gecko way is slower, hence producing some kind of bug/delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use this code:

```
var results = [];
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'debug',
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false, // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
    loadPlugins: false, // use these settings
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'
  }
});


casper.start('http://google.co.uk/', function(){});

casper.then(function(){
    casper.click('input[name="q"]');
    casper.sendKeys('input[name="q"]', 'casperjs');
});

casper.then(function(){
    casper.click('input[name="btnK"]');
});

casper.wait(5000, function() {
//this.echo(this.getHTML('form[action="/search"]'))
    results = casper.evaluate(function() {
                return document.title;
                });
});



casper.run(function() {
       this.echo(results).exit();
   });
```

Comment: Hey, it worked. How did you code fixed it? (Sorry, I'm a CasperJS beginner.)

Comment: Hey, first use the click event outside the evaluate function(you can use casper.click('')) and wait some time to get the title of page

Comment: I see, thanks! So why is it better to use the click event outside of `evaluate` in this case?

Comment: Because the evaluate function is executed in the page DOM environnment(client side) and casper.click('') is executed in the PhantomJS and CasperJS environnement.